# Linux mutexes must be global?

Tags: android, linux, multithreading

Most of the examples I'm looking at on the Web have pthread_mutex_t sitting at the top of the file in the global space and I think I read somewhere that Linux mutexes have to be global.  Is this true?

edit:
I have some Win32 multithreading code that I'm porting over to Linux.  For the windows code, there are several wrapper functions that encapsulate things like mutex creation and locking/unlocking.  My understanding is that every synchronization primitive that's created through one of the `Create()` API calls in Windows returns a HANDLE that can be stored in an instance field and then used later.  In this case, it's used in the Lock() function, which is wrapper around WaitForSingleObject().  For Linux, could I simply store the mutex in an instance field and call `pthread_mutex_lock()/pthread_cond_wait()` in the Lock() function and expect the same behavior as on Windows?

```
Nv_Mutex::Nv_Mutex(Nv_XprocessID name)
{

#if defined(WIN32)
    if((handle = ::CreateMutexA(0, false, name)) == NULL)
    {
        throw Nv_EXCEPTION(XCPT_ResourceAllocationFailure, GetLastError());
    }

    isCreator = !(::GetLastError() == ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS);
#else
    if (name == Nv_XprocessID_NULL) {
        /*
        pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;                     // Fast
        pthread_mutex_t recmutex = PTHREAD_RECURSIVE_MUTEX_INITIALIZER_NP;     // Recursive
        pthread_mutex_t errchkmutex = PTHREAD_ERRORCHECK_MUTEX_INITIALIZER_NP; // Errorcheck
        */
        mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
        // attributes??

        if (pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL) != 0) {
            throw Nv_EXCEPTION(XCPT_ResourceAllocationFailure, GetLastError());
        }
    }
    else {
        // insert code for named mutex (needed for shared mutex across processes) here.
    }

    //isCreator = !(GetLastError() == EBUSY);
#endif
}

bool                
Nv_Mutex::Lock(const char *f, int l, Nv_uint32 timeout)
{

    switch(WaitForSingleObject(handle, timeout))
    {
        case WAIT_OBJECT_0:
            file = f;
            line = l;
            return true;

        case WAIT_TIMEOUT:
            return false;
    }

    throw Nv_EXCEPTION(XCPT_WaitFailed, GetLastError());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they can scoped. There is nothing special about the actual mutex pointer.

Answer (score 1):

You have the requirement a bit wrong. Mutexes do not need to be global, however, you cannot statically initialize a non-static mutex. But you do not need to statically initialize a mutex prior to calling `pthread_mutex_init` on it, because that initializes it. So just don't use static initializers and instead call `pthread_mutex_init`.

It will actually work, but this is by luck due to the details of the implementation. Please don't rely on an implementation detail.

> Static initialization is legal only for statically ALLOCATED storage[.] ...  Although C syntax allows using the static initialization macros on "automatic" variables, this is specifically prohibited by the POSIX standard. It's not correct, and it's not portable. - [David Butenhof](http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Comp/comp.programming.threads/2005-11/msg00135.html)